# What's wrong with my temperature conversions?

Tags: c++, temperature, unit-conversion

In this program Iam trying to take 78 degrees Fahrenheit and return them in a class with the Celsius version and kelvin. But for some odd reason I'm just getting this as the output. What am I doing wrong?

This is my output.

```
78
0
273.15
```

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Temperature
{
public:

    double getTempKelvin();
    double getTempFahrenheit();
    double getTempCelcius();

    void setTempKelvin(double k);
    void setTempFahrenheit(double f);
    void setTempCelcius(double c);

private:
    double kelvin, fahrenheit, celcius;
    double c, f, k;
};

int main ()
{
    double c, f, k;
    Temperature Conv;

    Conv.setTempFahrenheit(f);
    Conv.setTempCelcius(c);
    Conv.setTempKelvin(k);
    cout << Conv.getTempFahrenheit() << endl;
    cout << Conv.getTempCelcius() << endl;
    cout << Conv.getTempKelvin() << endl;



    return 0;
}

void Temperature::setTempFahrenheit(double f)
{
    f = 78;
    fahrenheit = f;
}

void Temperature::setTempCelcius(double c)
{
    c = (5/9) * ( f - 32);
    celcius = c;
}

void Temperature::setTempKelvin(double k)
{
    k = c + 273.15;
    kelvin = k;
}




double Temperature::getTempFahrenheit()
{
    return fahrenheit;
}

double Temperature::getTempCelcius()
{
    return celcius;
}


double Temperature::getTempKelvin()
{
    return kelvin;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`5/9` is integer division and will result in `0`. You need to use doubles, Try:

```
void Temperature::setTempCelcius(double c)
{
    c = (5.0/9.0) * ( f - 32);
    celcius = c;
}
```

Comment: Yeah thast what 1 degree would be in Fahrenheit but for some reason its not reading c f or k i dont know why

Comment: @mystycs: it seems to be reading them fine.  Did you try this suggestion?

Comment: +1 this solves the initial problem the next will be if he doesn't call the methods in that order each time ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the 5/9 issue, you have three sets of variables called 'c', 'f', and 'k'. One set are the member variables in the class. Another set are the variables in `main`. The third set are the parameters inside the various `get*` functions.

It's not clear what purpose the variables in main serve, why the functions take parameters at all, or why your class has two sets of variables for the temperatures (both `c` and `celsius`, and so on) but if you give the sets of variables different names, it will become easier to understand why your program isn't working.

Comment: so would stepping through the program

Answer (score 0):

Seems that my problem was that i was clearning the k c and f double so i just removed them from the functions.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
double c, f, k;
class Temperature
{
public:

    double getTempKelvin();
    double getTempFahrenheit();
    double getTempCelcius();

    void setTempKelvin();
    void setTempFahrenheit();
    void setTempCelcius();

private:
    double kelvin, fahrenheit, celcius;
    double c, f, k;
};

int main ()
{
    Temperature Conv;

    Conv.setTempFahrenheit();
    Conv.setTempCelcius();
    Conv.setTempKelvin();
    cout << Conv.getTempFahrenheit() << endl;
    cout << Conv.getTempCelcius() << endl;
    cout << Conv.getTempKelvin() << endl;



    return 0;
}

void Temperature::setTempFahrenheit(){
    f = 78;
    fahrenheit = f;
}

void Temperature::setTempCelcius()
{
    c = (5.0/9.0) * ( f - 32);
    celcius = c;
}

void Temperature::setTempKelvin()
{
    k = c + 273.15;
    kelvin = k;
}




double Temperature::getTempFahrenheit()
{
    return fahrenheit;
}

double Temperature::getTempCelcius()
{
    return celcius;
}


double Temperature::getTempKelvin()
{
    return kelvin;
}
```

Comment: No, that wasn't your problem. Your problem was that you were calculating `5/9` instead of `5.0/9.0`, as Joe's answer told you.

Comment: @Rob There were multiple problems. `5/9` was one of them, but not the only one.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class temperature
{
    public :
    virtual void calculate(float)=0;
}; 
class ftoc : public temperature
{
    public :
    float c;
    void calculate(float f)
    { 
        c=(f-32)*5/9;
        cout<<"Temperature in celcius is : "<<c<<" `C "<<endl;
    }
};
class ftok : public temperature
{
    public : 
    float k;
    void calculate(float f)
    {
        k=(f+459.67)*5/9;
        cout<<"Themperature in kelvin is : "<<k<<" K "<<endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    float f;
    ftoc a;
    ftok b;
    cout<<"Enter the temperature : ";
    cin>>f;
    a.calculate(f);
    b.calculate(f);
    return 0;
}
```